# Theory of Retrieving Hashed Passwords

Tags: sqlite

This is a theory question, as I already know the following:

1. Hashes are not encryptions
2. Hashes can be broken https://crackstation.net/
3. That my code is not serious enough to be used on an enterprise site

But my question is just on the theory of it all.

In theory, if I stored a hashed password into a database, how could I check it when a user comes to log in? Is it that simple or is there a standard way to actually store and retrieve passwords in SQLite3?

If you can offer some SQLite3 code or guidance on where to start, that would be appreciated.

```
import sqlite3 
import hashlib

def encrypt_password(password):
    encrypted_pass = hashlib.sha1(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    return encrypted_pass

cemail = input("E: ")
cpassword = input("P: ")
connection = sqlite3.connect('/Users/Air/Desktop/users.db')
connection.create_function('encrypt', 1, encrypt_password)
cursor_v = connection.cursor()
cursor_v.execute("insert into user (cemail, cpassword) values    (?,encrypt(?))", (cemail, cpassword))
connection.commit()
cursor_v.close()
```

Comment: Don't use the term encryption for hashing. They are different things entirely. You also need to store, verify and accept passwords safely, and this is not the way to do that.

Comment: Where was the term "encryption" used? Encryption is reversible, hashing is not, I know that. The term "encrypt" in the code was just a variable. As far as the overall code, if it is not the way to do it, how can it be done? This was my original question.

Comment: `def encrypt_password(password):` made me type that, heh

Comment: Okay, I've edited the question. I am just looking for some guidance on this; pretty anxious to get started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with passwords, there's an absolute ton of information you need to know as a minimum:

Firstly, hashing passwords must be *slow*, which is the exact opposite of what a hash function is usually intended for.

Use bcrypt or PBKDF2 for this purpose. MD5/SHA1/256/512 are not sufficient for a password and offer no real protection when faced with a GPU-based bruteforcer (such as hashcat).

Second, verification of passwords **must be in constant-time**, aka they must complete in the same time regardless of the length of a string.

String comparison functions are at risk of a timing attack, and this means that the hash can be deduced by repeatedly giving different inputs to your verification function until enough information about the hash is revealed.

To get around this, use a cryptography library that does this for you.

If you have no other choice, the following pseudocode should help you see how a constant-time algorithm generally works (though you should still use a library!)

```
def verify(hash, input):
    key = secure_random(32)
    hash = hmac_sha_512(key, hash)
    input = hmac_sha_512(key, bcrypt(input))
    results = []        

    for i, letter in input
       results.add(hash[i] === letter)

    return false not in results
```

Thirdly, passwords should have a cryptographically random salt used throughout the hashing. A *secure random* source of randomness is generally taken from `/dev/urandom` or a library dedicated to it.

To answer the question of *Well how do I verify a password if I can't see the original value?* — simple, just hash whatever a user gives you and see if the hash matches the one in the database. But see above for the huge pitfall there.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly the kind of information that I was looking for. Let's say I use a salt on the hash, this would generate a random number then change the sequence. So how would I be able to regenerate that when a user types in his/her password?

Comment: @VictorEliasRodriguez you should store the salt as well as the hash so you can use it. Many password hashing libraries will append the salt to the password hash to make this easier (bcrypt, for example). With PBKDF2 you should store this salt somewhere you can fetch it easily.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot retrieve hashed password but compare new password whether it is the same. `IF HASH(new_password) == hashed_password_in_db THEN ..ok.. ELSE ..wrong password...`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. If I hash "ABC" for example, would that always be the same? If so, how it could be done so that it would be random every time, but also able to be matched?

Comment: The hash is always the same. I suppose you want to protect against replay attack with "random" hash. It will require additional encryption/hashing. For example, the server can send current date/time. Client side send 2 hashes: HASH(entered_password) and HASH(HASH(entered_password) + datetime). The server compare HASH(entered_password) with hash_in_database and check second hash with start date/time of current session to avoid replay attacks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still vulnerable to a timing attack.